# Must I re-populate Zend_Form fields after the post back manually?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

After a post back, suppose validation fails and I want to show the form again with errors, I find that the form is empty, must I repopulate the form fields manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method isValid populate the form field. You don't have to repopulate manually.

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way to handle form processing is to use something like

```
$form = new My_Form;
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()
    && $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
    // process form and redirect (PRG pattern)
}
$this->view->form = $form;
```

This way, your form is shown on the first request and if not valid, is re-shown with the submitted values and any validation messages.

Comment: And do you declare `$form = new Application_Form_Project()` before all that before the code snipplet? If so I think values will be empty? I am getting "Value is required & can't be empty error"

Comment: I do just as you and Phil describe: `$form = new Application_Form_Project()` followed by `isPost()` and `isValid()` checks. On failed validation, my form is filled with the posted data. Something else going on here?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using some custom isValid don't forget your form also has a populate() function.

So

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
if(!$myForm->isValid($data)){
    $myForm->populate($data);
}
```

No need to do it by hand thats for sure.

Of course dont forget to assign the same object you did the isValid - populate calls on

```
$this->view->form = $myForm;
```

After the checks.